# How to create a new list dynamically with Button click?

Tags: listview, flutter, dynamic, widget, draggable

I am working with Draggable(images) in Flutter. The aim is to provide a button, on click of which new DragTarget will be formed and the user can drag the image to the drag target. A list of images dragged in the target will be displayed in the respective DragTarget.

eg: Given a few images of Pokemons, group them according to their type. Users can create new DragTarget to group similar pokemon.

Issue:

I am currently adding the dropped pokemon in a single list and displaying it. Hence I can see same pokemon in all the DraggedTargets.

[image: like this]

please watch this screen recording for the issue: 
https://youtu.be/XnJv3LiGfic

I am maintaining a list of widgets(DragTarget) named dragTargetList and wrapping the list to display all the DragTargets by using setState() for adding one more to the list.

Each DragTarget contains a list of images named droppedImages maintaining images dropped in the target.

How do I create a new list on new DragTarget Creation and maintain it in a way that each DragTarget displays only a list of images dropped in it?

```
List<Widget> getDragTargetList=[];
List<String> droppedImages=[]; //tplaceholder, we need dynamic list instead of //this
Widget temp(){

  return Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Row(children:<Widget>[
      Wrap( children: List.generate(imageList.length, (e) => Draggable(child:
      Container(child: Image.network( imageList[e])),
          feedback: Container(height:10, width:10, color: Colors.lightBlue,),
          childWhenDragging: Container())
      )),]),

      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: (){setState(){getDragTargetList.add(getDragTarget());}},
      ),

      Wrap(children: List.generate(getDragTargetList.length, (e)=>getDragTargetList[e]),)
    ],
  );
}
Widget getDragTarget(){
  return DragTarget<String>(
    builder: (BuildContext context, List<String> incoming, List rejected) {
      return Container(
        color: Colors.cyan,
        child:
        Wrap(
          children: List.generate(droppedImages.length, (e)=> //need to create and maintain dynamic list here
              Container(height: 20, width: 20, child:_getCircularAvatar(droppedImages[e]),)),
        ),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        height: 80,
        width: 200,
      );
    },
    onWillAccept: (data){return true;},
    //=> data == emoji,
    onAccept: (data) {
      setState(() {
        droppedImages.add(data);
      });
    },
    onLeave: (data) {},
  );
}
```

Please help me with

Comment: What is list Incoming in Draggable? Can it help?

Comment: do you want to drag pockemon to first target after adding second ?

Comment: Could you post the entire code so we can compile it and try to solve your problem?

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya yes

Comment: @PabloBarrera sure

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue by taking List of List instead of only List and manage it using index.

**Note:- I have used ListView instead of Wrap only for avoid overflow issue.**

Check this.

```
List<List<String>> droppedImages = [];
int getDragTargetListLength = 0;

Widget temp() {
return Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    SizedBox(
      height: 20,
    ),
    Row(children: <Widget>[
      Wrap(
        children: List.generate(
          imageList.length,
          (e) => Draggable(
            data: imageList[e],
            child: Container(
              width: 80,
              height: 50,
              child: Image.asset(
                imageList[e],
              ),
            ),
            feedback: Container(
              width: 80,
              height: 50,
              child: Image.asset(
                imageList[e],
              ),
            ),
            childWhenDragging: Container(),
            onDragCompleted: () {
              print("drag completed");
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ]),
    SizedBox(
      height: 20,
    ),
    Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.blue),
      child: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.add),
        color: Colors.white,
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            droppedImages.add([]);
            getDragTargetListLength++;
          });
        },
      ),
    ),
    SizedBox(
      height: 20,
    ),
    Container(
      height: 150,
      child: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: getDragTargetListLength,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int e) {
          return getDragTarget(e);
        },
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
}



Widget getDragTarget(int index) {
    return DragTarget<String>(
      builder: (BuildContext context, List<String> incoming, List rejected) {
        return Container(
          color: Colors.cyan,
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
          child: Wrap(
            children: List.generate(
                droppedImages[index].length,
                (e) => //need to create and maintain dynamic list here
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                      height: 30,
                      width: 30,
                      child: _getCircularAvatar(droppedImages[index][e]),
                    )),
          ),
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          height: 150,
          width: 200,
        );
      },
      onWillAccept: (data) {
        return true;
      },
      //=> data == emoji,
      onAccept: (data) {
        setState(() {
          droppedImages[index].add(data);
        });
      },
      onLeave: (data) {
        print(data);
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I went through the documentation again and understood that DragTarget has three attributes:

- Builder
- Candidate List: The list of items hovering above the target
- Rejected List: The list of items that were not dropped into the target

Clearly, every Drag Target maintains it's own candidate list. This was the answer.

I just created a temporary list: temp, every time the Drag Target was created and added the candidate list items to it.

If the item existed in the rejected list, I removed them with setState from temp

I am maintaining the indexes of DragTarget and items in it in a ditch.

Please let me know if anybody needs the code for the same!

Thanks for helping!